# Maximum decreasing prefix with iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing next permutation algorithm in C++.

It is forbidden to use for and while (we are supposed to do everything with iterators only).

The first step of the algorithm is to get maximum non-increasing suffix. I am strucked, because I don't understand how to find something in vector by condition using only iterators.

Comment: std::find, std::for_each come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::find` or `std::for_each` defined in `algorithm` e.g. example using `C++14`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,5,7};

    auto f = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5);
    if (f != std::end(v)) {
        std::cout << "found element 5" << std::endl;
    }

    std::for_each(
        std::begin(v),
        std::end(v),
        [](int n) {
            if (n == 5) {
                std::cout << "found element 5" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    );
}
```